# Chart.js - Display a reference area in which the value should be

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In the picture below you can see a line-chart (created with Chart.js). I just have one item with different values from time to time. This item have a reference range.

[image: Current Chart]

**As example:**

- Reference range is: 80 - 110
- Item values are: [100, 110, 99, ....]

Now I would like to display this reference range without data points in the chart, that the user can see if a value is out of the reference range.

My question is how I can do that. I've already looked for possible ways to do that, but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by using Chart.js's annotation feature.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Item',
            data: [100, 110, 99, 105, 115, 90, 105],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false
                }
            }]
        },
        annotation: {
            annotations: [{
                type: 'box',
                drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw',
                yScaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                yMin: 80,
                yMax: 110,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                borderWidth: 2
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you ADITYA :) Didn't know that chart.js offers such an option.